# How can I use Codable Object which is not NSObject in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, codable

I am working on a project which is mix of Objective C and Swift.

I have some Codable objects which I need to use in Objective C but these are not inherited from `NSObject`. If I make them inherit from `NSObject` I am not able to convert to json string using `JSONEncoder`

```
class Sample:NSObject, Codable
{

var name:String = "Lucien"
var data:[String:String] = ["token":"121bnkfjas"]

}
let sample = Sample()

   let jsonData =   try JSONEncoder().encode(sample)
   let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

I have a `jsonString` as `{}`.

If I make only Confirm to Codable protocol it is working properly.

```
 class Sample:Codable
    {

    var name:String = "Lucien"
    var data:[String:String] = ["token":"121bnkfjas"]

    }
    let sample = Sample()

       let jsonData =   try JSONEncoder().encode(sample)
       let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

This jsonString is proper.

How can I use only Codable objects in Objective C?

Comment: Means you want to use Swift Codable object with code of objective c?

Comment: Yes I want to use Swift Codable object in Objective C.

Comment: You can't access anything which has generics from objc, but you can have "middleware" class that trigger the job you need or convert objects into simpler versions without generics